# "warning: control reaches end of non-void function" but actually the function is declared as int and return an int

Tags: c, gcc

I have this function:

```
int firstHeapArray (IntHeapArray h) {
    if(!emptyHeapArray(h))
        return h.array[0];
}
```

It's declared as int, and this is the IntHeapArray struct:

```
typedef struct intHeapArray {
    int *array;
    int size;
} IntHeapArray;
```

Can you say why I get this warning while compiling?

```
heap-test.c: In function ‘firstHeapArray’:
heap.h:31:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is stating that you have a method that is not a `void` return, but you're reaching the end without returning a value.  You need to return a valid int value.

The problem is here:

```
int firstHeapArray (IntHeapArray h) {
    if(!emptyHeapArray(h))
        return h.array[0];

    // If emptyHeapArray(h) is true, you reach here...

   // You need to return SOMETHING here to remove the warning
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: While its good practice, its not mandatory to return a value in either case. That's why the compiler reports a _warning_ instead of an _error_.

Comment: @K-ballo True - edited the comment to be more explicit about that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it's clear. But if it return a 0, the answer will be wrong. The function shall return the lowest value in the heap... and if the heap is empty, 0 isn't the lowest value. So... what to do? Keep the warning?

Comment: @Zagorax This is where exceptions in C++ come into play.  If hte heap is empty, and you call this,  what do you want as an "answer"?  Some people return a value known to never be valid (ie: a negative value, some "magic" number, etc), but that is problematic if there is no bad value.

Comment: @ReedCopsey - Uhm... I don't know... Maybe I should declare the functions as int* and return NULL if it's empty and the pointer if it's not. I need a false value if it's empty and this value can't be an integer because every integer can be there.

Comment: @Zagorax You can also return a "success" flag, and pass the int in by pointer, setting the value when successful.

Answer (score 1):

If `emptyHeapArray(h)` returns true, you don't return anything. Then the control reaches the end of the non-void function `firstHeapArray`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler deduces that when the `if` test fails there's no return statement if can execute.

Comment: So there's no way to avoid this warning? I don't have any integer to return if the test fail.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `firstHeapArray` does not return if `emptyHeapArray(h) == true`.

This is undefined behavior, which means anything can happen, most likely that anyone using this function when the heap is empty will potentially receive a random value.

You can handle this case returning a success flag:

```
bool firstHeapArray (IntHeapArray h, int * out_value) {
   if(!emptyHeapArray(h))
   {
       *value = h.array[0];
       return true; //success
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function must return value in either case:

```
int firstHeapArray (IntHeapArray h) {
    if(!emptyHeapArray(h))
        return h.array[0];

    return 0;
}
```

In you example it returns value only if some condition is met.

Comment: While its good practice, its not mandatory to return a value in either case.

Comment: @K-ballo Not mandatory but introduces undefined behavior. From my point of view it is not acceptable.

Comment: @Ugo: It introduces undefined behavior _only_ if someone attempts to read the result of the function... Anyway, from my point of view is still unacceptable.

Comment: @K-ballo: imagine `double mysin(double x) { if (x >= 0.0) return sin(x); }` It is just plain nonsense to return bogus. And it is against the law, and the compiler warns you about it.

Comment: @wildplasser: While I concur its just plain nonsense, its not against the law. The standard allows to leave the body of a function without returning anything, and specifies that is only _undefined behavior_ if you try to read the result of such function call.