# I get a warning for a function and I do not know how to write the function so I won't get that warning anymore

Tags: c, search, tree, warnings

So this is the code for a simple searching of a node in a tree based on an `id` of that node:

```
NodeT *searchNode(NodeT *parent, int id)
{
    if(parent == NULL) printf("\nThere is no tree.");
    if(parent->id == id)
        return parent;
    else
    {
        if(parent->left != NULL) searchNode(parent->left, id);
        if(parent->right != NULL) searchNode(parent->right, id);
    }
}
```

Also I am getting this: **warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|**

The nodes are defined as follows:

```
typedef struct node_type
{
    char id;
    struct node_type *left, *right;
} NodeT;
```

Is there any way I can get rid of that warning?

Comment: The warning is quite explicit. What does the function return if `parent->id != id`? Functions must **always** return something if you declared that they do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["warning: control reaches end of non-void function" but actually the function is declared as int and return an int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964528/warning-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-but-actually-the-function-is)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot. I figured it out that if I will replace the line `if(parent->left != NULL) searchNode(parent->left, id);` with `return searchNode(parent->left, id);` then the program will function normally without any warning. Same goes for the next line: `if(parent->right != NULL) searchNode(parent->right, id);`.

Comment: @ISimion what if you have a left and a right node, but the result is to be found in the right node? You'll return the result from the left and not look at the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Your function only returns something under certain circumstances. The warning is telling you that you need to return something under all circumstances. It's a very important warning in the case of your code cos because it also highlights several bugs.

```
if(parent == NULL) printf("\nThere is no tree.");
if(parent->id == id)
```

What happens if `parent` is `NULL`? It prints out the error message and then continues on to the next line and will crash. You want that first `if` to also have a return statement if it's true so that the code doesn't continue or put the rest of the function code into an else block.

Next, what happens if your tree has several nodes in it? You traverse the tree, but ignore the results! And if you search for a node that doesn't exist, you also don't return anything for that either.

So you should change your code to `return NULL` if it can't find a result or return the result passed back to it from recursively calling itself.